# A syntactic error in the question with the expression let in the scheme language

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to the scheme scheme, I started learning the scheme scheme on my own independently. I solve questions to improve my language. There is one question I solved correctly, but I can not figure out where the mistake is. I think I wrote the let in the wrong place. I'm trying for hours to figure out the problem, I do not know where it is.
I tried to play with the brackets and change their position but I feel it does not help and it confuses me more.

[image]

Everything works fine, except for the last code.

Would appreciate help

source code:

```
#lang racket

(define(make_times_n n)
  (lambda (x) (* x n)))

(define (square2 x)
  ((make_times_n x) x))

(define (make-parabola a b c)
  (lambda (x) (+ ((make_times_n a) (square2 x)) ((make_times_n b) x) c)))

(define (make-triple a b c)
  (lambda (x) (* (- x a) (- x b) (- x c))))

(define (make_triple_or_parabola_N a b c N)
  ( let* (triple ((make-triple a b c) N)) (parabola  ((make-parabola a b c) N) ) )
  (if ( > triple parabola ) triple parabola)
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some brackets, this is the correct way to write and indent a `let*`:

```
(define (make_triple_or_parabola_N a b c N)
  (let* ((triple   ((make-triple a b c) N))
         (parabola ((make-parabola a b c) N)))
    (if (> triple parabola)
        triple
        parabola)))
```

Compare it with what you wrote:

```
(let* (triple   ((make-triple a b c) N))
      (parabola ((make-parabola a b c) N))
  ...)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%2A%29%29) we need a couple of extra `()` surrounding the list of variable-value pairs, like this:

```
(let* ((triple   ((make-triple a b c) N))
       (parabola ((make-parabola a b c) N)))
  ...)
```